# How to run Symfony console command inside the docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, console-application, symfony-3.4

I am trying to run Symfony 3 console command inside of my docker container but not able to getting proper output.

#### docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      target: symfony_docker_php
      args:
        SYMFONY_VERSION: ${SYMFONY_VERSION:-}
        STABILITY: ${STABILITY:-stable}
    volumes:
      # Comment out the next line in production
      - ./:/srv/app:rw,cached
      # If you develop on Linux, comment out the following volumes to just use bind-mounted project directory from host
      - /srv/app/var/
      - /srv/app/var/cache/
      - /srv/app/var/logs/
      - /srv/app/var/sessions/
    environment:
      - SYMFONY_VERSION

  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      target: symfony_docker_nginx
    depends_on:
      - app
    volumes:
      # Comment out the next line in production
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
      - ./public:/srv/app/public:ro
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

My console command
`docker-compose exec nginx php bin/console`

It returns the following response
`the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'`

Answer (score 1):

Copy from https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/

To disable this behavior, you can either the -T flag to disable pseudo-tty allocation.

```
docker-compose exec -T nginx <command>
```

Or, set COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI value as 1

```
export COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI=1
```

For php bin/console to run you need to run from app container like below.

docker-compose exec -T app php bin/console

Comment: I set COMPOSE_INTERACTIVE_NO_CLI value as 1 and try again with your reference command, it showing the following error `$ docker-compose exec -T nginx php bin/console
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"php\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown`

Comment: Now about this error >> you are trying to run PHP command on Nginx container. If you are using the default Nginx image shouldn't have PHP inside that. I belive you are trying to use PHP from symfony_docker_php container.

Comment: I am following this repo to setup docker for symfony project `https://github.com/dunglas/symfony-docker`

Comment: So 1st you need to make "docker compose up", then your both container will start. You can verify that by docker ps command. If both containers are running you can check http://localhost your application. Also, you can verify PHP from app container  like this "docker-compose exec -T app php --version".

Comment: I already did that and the console returns the following PHP version `$ docker-compose exec -T app php --version
PHP 7.2.21 (cli) (built: Aug 20 2019 23:29:01) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.21, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by Derick Rethans`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198541/discussion-between-sounak-saha-and-abdul-awal).

Comment: Okay, please check the chat console